Apriori energy estimate for strange PDE: $\partial_{tt} \partial_{yy} u + \partial_{xx} u = F$
I have this rather obscure-looking (weak-form of a) PDE
$$(\partial_y u'', \partial_y v)+(\partial_x u, \partial_x v) = (f,\partial_x v)+(g,v)\quad\forall v\in \mathcal{D}.$$
Here $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $L^2$ inner product, $u(t)$ is unknown on a bounded 2D domain $\Omega$ for every time $t$, $''$ denotes the (second) time derivative, $\mathcal{D}$ is the testfunction space, and $f,g\in L^2$.
Suppose, we can bound
$$\Vert u \Vert\leq  \Vert \partial_y u \Vert\qquad \text{(*)},$$
where $\Vert\cdot\Vert:=\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}$.

Goal: apriori energy estimates for $u$ and $\partial_y u$.


What i have tried: choosing $v:=u'$ which gives
$$
\begin{align}
(\partial_y u'', \partial_y u')+(\partial_x u, \partial_x u') &= (f,\partial_x u')+(g,u')\\
\iff\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert \partial_y u'\Vert^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert \partial_x u \Vert^2 &= (f,\partial_x u')+(g,u')\\
&\leq \Vert f\Vert \Vert \partial_x u' \Vert + \Vert g\Vert \Vert u' \Vert\\
&\stackrel{\text{(*)}}{\leq}\Vert f\Vert \Vert \partial_x u' \Vert + \Vert g\Vert \Vert \partial_y u' \Vert.
\end{align}
$$
Now i can apply Young's inequality to rewrite the products on the RHS into sums (i will ignore the constants for readability):
$$...\leq \Vert f\Vert^2 + \Vert \partial_x u' \Vert^2 + \Vert g\Vert^2 + \Vert \partial_y u' \Vert^2.$$
Finally I would like to apply Gronwall's Lemma to
$$\frac{d}{dt}E\leq F + C E,$$
with $E:=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert \partial_y u'\Vert^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert \partial_x u \Vert^2$, and $F:=\Vert f\Vert^2 + \Vert g\Vert^2$, so that i can bound
$$E\leq \text{known stuff}.$$
Of course that does not work because one the RHS i have
$$\Vert \partial_x u' \Vert\quad\text{ and not } \quad \Vert \partial_x u \Vert.$$

Question 1: Can we find bounds for $u,\partial_y u$ somehow?
Question 2: What further assumptions could help me? Regularity on $f,g$? Or another inequality, like e.g. $\Vert u \Vert\leq  \Vert \partial_x u \Vert$? Can one bound $\Vert \partial_x u' \Vert\leq \Vert \partial_x u \Vert$ by assuming something for the time-interval?
Question 3: Can we prove that such a bound is strictly impossible for the given setting?

Let me know if the question is suited for this forum, or if it should be posted on MathOverflow instead.

Ok I found the "trick" I needed: one can integrate by parts the term
$$(f,\partial_x u') = - (\partial_x f, u').$$
After this, one follows the approach I already sketched above: apply the Cauchy-Schwartz and Youngs inequality and then use the inequality
$$||u'||\leq ||\partial_y u'||.$$
Then one can apply Grönwall.
The necessary assumption is that $f$ is at least $H^1$.
